# Delete works differently for different users on the same machine (macOS)

Tags: osx, frames

I'm totally dumbfounded. I have two users on the same machine running macOS. Both of them have the same `.emacs`, same iTerm profile. However the "delete" key works correctly as backspace for on one of them, but doesn't on the other. I know I can use `M-x normal-erase-is-backspace-mode` to work around the issue, but it's very annoying. I don't really care whether it behaves one way or the other, as long as it's consistent. Any good suggestions on what might cause the discrepancy?

P.S. this only happens when I run emacs with `-nw`. In the normal X window mode the delete/backspace works for both users

Comment: Can you find no differences? Same keyboard? What about the default behavior (`emacs -Q`) - is it the same for both?

Comment: Added more info. This only happens when running without X window. With `emacs -Q -nw` the behavior is still inconsistent between the two users.

Comment: Sounds like they're using different terminal emulators, correct?

Comment: Are they both running the same Emacs? (a frequent issue on macOS seems to be that on the terminal `$PATH` is not setup the same as GUI, causing some ancient version of Emacs (like 22 or something?) to be used)

Comment: Yeah it's the same Emacs. I used explicit path to test. (P.S. I do have multiple Emacs installed, but the behavior is the same regardless of the version)

Comment: FWIW my suspicion was that I messed up the iTerm profile on one of the users. But the behavior remains the same after I exported the profile from the other user. Also the same thing happens when I tried it in the default Terminal app. It's highly unlikely (but not impossible) that I messed up the profiles for both.

Comment: @Dan it does look like the problem is in the terminal emulator. However I have tried both iTerm and Terminal. Perhaps there is some system level setting that I messed up?

Comment: Could it be a shell setting in .profile or .bashrc? Look for something like 'stty erase'.

Comment: Wow that's it, @AlanThird you totally saved me. Please add it to the answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this only affects Emacs running in the terminal, it's probably a terminal setting of some description. You've already looked at the iterm2 and terminal settings, but you should check the users' shell startup scripts (.profile, .bashrc, .zshrc, etc.).

The usual method of remapping the delete key is to use something like:

```
stty erase <backspace character>
```